# Reveal animation when open dialog like Whatsapp?

Tags: android, animation, dialog, whatsapp

I would like to open user info's dialog with reveal animation like how Whatsapp does.

[image: clarification Image]

Any idea?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this open source library [FabDialogMorph](https://github.com/hujiaweibujidao/FabDialogMorph)

[Here's](https://youtu.be/4L4fLrWDvAU?t=21m22s) Nick Butcher explains mechanics behind it.

Comment: I came through this early today, and this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the great video as well, it has more stuff to get.