# How to take a view to the front and make other views stay behind it in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make a android app, so that when i click a particular view it takes it to the front of every view and let other views stay behind it becoming slightly dim in color .
E.g: This whatsapp profile show layout.( the profile is on top of every thing and we can interact with it)

[image]

I want to know the relevant keywords, topics or name of particular widgets to learn to finally implement this view along with the animation. Any approach to reach the solution would also be appreciated .

I have tried using different ways bring image to front, etc.. but that didn't solve the problem .

Comment: https://medium.com/@xabaras/creating-a-custom-dialog-with-dialogfragment-f0198dab656d

Comment: check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41297199/reveal-animation-when-open-dialog-like-whatsapp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send view to back ? How to control the z-order programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759036/how-to-send-view-to-back-how-to-control-the-z-order-programmatically)

Comment: You can create a custom alert dialog. For tutorial refer this link - https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-custom-dialog-example/. change the layout  of dialog as per your need.

Comment: @Syed No need to create custom dialog for doing this..

Comment: @PrachiSingh ok, let me try both options, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a **custom alert dialog** and inflating a layout into it.

```
public class CvvHelpDialog extends Dialog {

    public CvvHelpDialog(@NonNull Activity context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_cvv_help);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        lp.copyFrom(getWindow().getAttributes());
        lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

    }
}
```

For R.layout.*dialog_cvv_help*, you can design a layout as your requirement. You can display it by simply using the below lines of code.

```
CvvHelpDialog cvvDialog = new CvvHelpDialog(getActivity());
cvvDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an `activity` or `fragment` with a transparent background and image to the center of the `activity` or `fragment`. And just start the new activity or display the fragment.

Or you can also use a `DialogFragment` for this purpose.

You can use **Element transition** for the animation to pop a view to the front from other like WhatsApp profile picture.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dialog .
The screen behind dialog automatically get dim.You don't have to do anything.

https://androidexample.com/Custom_Dialog_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=88

Answer (score 1):

Just Create dialog and add your custom view for doing this...like this

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder =new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_layout,null);
builder.setView(view);
builder.show();
```

when dialog will appear..background will be transparent automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view with the custom view in the center and gray background around this view in the same layout. And when you will need to show - make it visible and set isEnable = false for background viewgroup